# How to configure Spring's RestTemplate to return null when HTTP status of 404 is returned

Tags: java, spring, rest, jaxb

I am calling a REST service that returns XML, and using `Jaxb2Marshaller` to marshal my classes  (e.g. `Foo`, `Bar`, etc). So my client code looks like so:

```
    HashMap<String, String> vars = new HashMap<String, String>();
    vars.put("id", "123");

    String url = "http://example.com/foo/{id}";

    Foo foo = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Foo.class, vars);
```

When the look-up on the server side fails it returns a 404 along with some XML. I end up getting an `UnmarshalException` thrown as it cannot read the XML.

```
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"exception"). Expected elements are <{}foo>,<{}bar>
```

The body of the response is:

```
<exception>
    <message>Could not find a Foo for ID 123</message>
</exception>
```

How can I configure the `RestTemplate` so that `RestTemplate.getForObject()` returns `null` if a 404 happens?

Comment: `getForObject`, by default, should be throwing a `HttpClientErrorException` with a 404. How have you configured your `RestTemplate`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I do not have access to the code any more, but the default behaviour you describe sounds like what I expected at the time. (I should get into the habit of stating the versions in future questions.)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
Foo foo = null;
try {
    foo = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Foo.class, vars);
} catch (HttpClientErrorException ex)   {
    if (ex.getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND) {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

To capture 404 NOT FOUND errors specifically you can catch `HttpClientErrorException.NotFound`

```
Foo foo;
try {
    foo = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Foo.class, vars);
} catch (HttpClientErrorException.NotFound ex) {
    foo = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to capture server related error, this will handle internal server error,

```
}catch (HttpServerErrorException e) {
        log.error("server error: "+e.getResponseBodyAsString());
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        EventAPIResponse eh = mapper.readValue(e.getResponseBodyAsString(), EventAPIResponse.class);
        log.info("EventAPIResponse toString "+eh.toString());
```